# "standard" dll created in vb6 gives access violation when called in python

Tags: c++, python, dll, vb6

I created a "standard" dll using vb6 via the hack in: http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2005/04/26/create_dll.html?page=3. Let's call this myVB6dll.

A function in myVB6dll (call it myVB6dllFunc()) calls HidD_GetHidGuid() from hid.dll and returns a byte of the GUID (for testing purposes). When I call myVB6dllFunc() from a test program in vb6, it returns the proper value. However, when called from a python2.7 test program, it throws 'access violation writing 0x00000009c'.

A similar dll written in C++ works when called from either VB6 or Python2.7.

So, is the VB6 dll really not a standard dll, and the hack does not really work (but it does work with simple test cases from vb6 dlls called by Python, such as if I return the sum of two integers)? Is there a way to make it work in Python? What is the difference between the two dlls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to export function from a VB6 dll is using [vbAdvance add-in](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/) and it's freeware now.

The problem you are facing is that you need to initialize VB6 run-time on the thread that's calling your export. This includes initializing COM apartment (STA) too. Easiest would be to create an instance of a VB6 class from your python code.

Initializing VB6 run-time "manually" in your export function is much more difficult and would need to use a custom typelib for calling API functions (can't use declares or built-in VB6 functions before initializing run-time).

Here is a function I'm using

```
Private Function pvInitVbRuntime() As Boolean
'    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "pvInitVbRuntime" '
    Const PROGID_DUMMY  As String = LIB_NAME & ".cDummy"
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    lIdx = GetModuleHandle("MSVBVM60.DLL")
    lIdx = GetProcAddress(lIdx, "__vbaSetSystemError")
    Call RtlMoveMemory(lIdx, ByVal lIdx + 9, 4)
    Call RtlMoveMemory(lIdx, ByVal lIdx, 4)
    If TlsGetValue(lIdx) <> 0 Then
        Call CoCreateInstance(CLSIDFromProgID(PROGID_DUMMY), Nothing, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, VBGUIDFromString("{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"), Nothing)
        pvInitVbRuntime = True
    Else
'        Call APIOutputDebugString(GetCurrentThreadId() & ": not a VB thread [" & LIB_NAME & "." & MODULE_NAME & "." & FUNC_NAME & "]" & vbCrLf) '
    End If
End Function
```

All API functions (`GetModuleHandle`, `GetProcAddress`, `RtlMoveMemory`, `TlsGetValue`, `CoCreateInstance`, `CLSIDFromProgID`, `VBGUIDFromString`, `APIOutputDebugString`) are declared in a custom typelib. Basicly it creates a dummy VB6 class (called `cDummy`) on the thread. The function fails if apartment is not already initialized (`CoInitialize` is not called).

Comment: Thank you wqw. I am digesting your response.

Comment: @tosa: VB6 is using TLS (thread-local storage) for global variables so VB6 global variables have "copies" per thread. The hack with `__vbaSetSystemError` is to figure out the TLS slot/index the run-time should be using in the current process. If the TLS slot with this index is not set then the run-time is not initialized yet (so there are no global variables and no error handling is available). Notice that `MSVBVM60.DLL` is already loaded because your VB6 dll specifies it in its import section so `GetModuleHandle` will never fail.